# Pandas: create new column containing the corresponding value of the maximum in another column by group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column containing the corresponding value of the maximum in another column by group. This is best explained by example:

```
data = {'group':['g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2'], 
                    'A':[3, 1, 8, 2, 6, -1, 0, 13, -4, 0, 1], 
                    'B':[5, 2, 3, 7, 11, -1, 4,-1, 1, 0, 2]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

The following solution works as a shortcut, but I have a feeling that there is a better way to do it:

```
df.loc[:, 'Amax'] = df.loc[df.groupby('group')['B'].idxmax(), 'A']
df.loc[:, 'Amax'] = df.groupby('group')['Amax'].transform('median')

   group   A   B  Amax
0     g1   3   5   6.0
1     g1   1   2   6.0
2     g1   8   3   6.0
3     g1   2   7   6.0
4     g1   6  11   6.0
5     g1  -1  -1   6.0
6     g2   0   4   0.0
7     g2  13  -1   0.0
8     g2  -4   1   0.0
9     g2   0   0   0.0
10    g2   1   2   0.0
```

Comment: Why do you say maximum, yet use `median`?

Comment: The first line creates a column of NaNs except where the index max is located. The median calculation ignores NaNs and because there is only one value in each group, the rest of the rows in the group are set to that single value. Its more of a workaround solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `transform`

```
df['Amax']=df.loc[df.groupby('group')['B'].transform('idxmax'),'A'].values
df
Out[42]: 
   group   A   B  Amax
0     g1   3   5     6
1     g1   1   2     6
2     g1   8   3     6
3     g1   2   7     6
4     g1   6  11     6
5     g1  -1  -1     6
6     g2   0   4     0
7     g2  13  -1     0
8     g2  -4   1     0
9     g2   0   0     0
10    g2   1   2     0
```

Comment: I tried this exact solution previously but I kept getting a duplicate axis error. Now I see my mistake: I didn't put .values at the end... Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), but because index is different assign array created by [`Series.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html):

```
df['Amax'] = df.set_index('A').groupby('group')['B'].transform('idxmax').to_numpy()
print(df)
   group   A   B  Amax
0     g1   3   5     6
1     g1   1   2     6
2     g1   8   3     6
3     g1   2   7     6
4     g1   6  11     6
5     g1  -1  -1     6
6     g2   0   4     0
7     g2  13  -1     0
8     g2  -4   1     0
9     g2   0   0     0
10    g2   1   2     0
```